# How to log a nested JSON object - Scala

Tags: java, scala, logging, logback

Example code:

```
   val source = """{ "name": "Patrick", "id":123 }"""
   val jsonAst = source.parseJson

   logger.info("Start of log", keyValue("body", jsonAst), "End of log")
```

In log it's `{}` for `"body"`.

I tried to convert `jsonAst` to a case class but it's still a `{}`.

And I'm expecting logs as

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2019-12-05T01:38:12.961-08:00",
  "message": "Start of log",
  "body": {
    "name": "Patrick",
    "id": 123
  }
}
```

Comment: What library for parsing json do you use?

Comment: import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.keyValue
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Also it would be better if you provide dependencies in `build.sbt`, from what you import packages, classes etc. And scala version. It will help others to reproduce the problem

Comment: I'm expecting {
  "@timestamp": "2019-12-05T01:38:12.961-08:00",
  "message": "Start of log",
  "body": {
   "name": "Patrick", 
   "id":123
  }
}

Comment: Better if you provide the expected output in the question. Also please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The problem maybe is in the keyValue function. the jsonAst is a well formed JsVale